# Using feynmf for Feynman Diagrams

Tags: feynman, feynmf

I am using \usepackage{feynmf} to draw Feynman diagrams. However, I have an issue with the labeling of my vertices. For some charts, it puts the vertex label right in the lines. For example, see the following figure for reference.
[image]

Can someone help me with how to change the location of the labels using the feynmf package? Here is my code to which the above image is output.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{feynmf}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{fmffile}{diagram}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(120,80)
        \fmfleft{i1}
        \fmfright{o1}
        \fmf{scalar}{i1,a}
        \fmf{scalar}{a,o1}
        \fmfdot{a}
        \fmflabel{$g$}{a}
   \end{fmfgraph*}
   \end{fmffile}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. **Always** attach code. When you post to this site, please always provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: You can use \usepackage{feynmp-auto} or \usepackage{feynmp} instead of \usepackage{feynmf} and all work.

Comment: Also, the `feynmf` documentation, page 23, explains that in order to control label placement you have to use `\fmfv` instead of `\fmflabel`.

Answer (score 1):

Here a MWE to resolve your question using `\fmfiv` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{diagram}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(120,80)
    \fmfleft{i1}
    \fmfright{o1}
    \fmf{scalar}{i1,i2}
    \fmf{scalar}{i2,o1}
    \fmfdot{i2}
    \fmfiv{l=$g$,l.a=90,l.d=.04w}{c}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}
    \end{document}
```

[image]